# Why is the Custom Megamenu not being cached at all?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

We have a custom megamenu that is not being cached at all and is called on every page. We think it is a good candidate that is slowing down the site especially when profiled on a site with many categories.

The `catalog_add_top_menu_items` observer is called every time and not cached:

[image: catalog-top-menu]

In `frontend/custom_theme/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`:

We are creating the main header and getting the the top links, search and topmenu in the normal way:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
...
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Then in the topmenu block: `RedLightBlinking_MegaMenu_Block_Page_Html_Topmenu extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`

it changes the template to a different one:

```
/**
     * Change template if Mega Menu is enabled
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if(Mage::helper('megamenu')->isMegaMenuEnabled()){
            $this->setTemplate('megamenu/page/html/megamenu.phtml');
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

Then in the template `frontend/custom_theme/default/template/megamenu/page/html/megamenu.phtml:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('dropdown', 'dropdown-menu') ?>
```

Which calls the `getHtml` function of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu` which dispatches the event.

So I am unsure why it is not caching at all.
What I tried was remove the `$this->setTemplate('megamenu/page/html/megamenu.phtml');` then I just moved the code in there to `topmenu.phtml`

**Update:And that worked. It seems like it now caches.**

**But I don't know why? Anyone have ideas?**

The layout is the standard `page.xml`:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
```

**It only caches the top menu per page. So first load of a unique page will always build the menu items from scratch. Then on subsequent requests, it is cached.**

Comment: Do you have news? i have the same problem

Comment: Nope, no news. Might need to use xdebug and step through the template code. There is a default cache time or something skipping the use of cache.